# How natural is it to use "will be held" to specify time?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I know another idiom "scheduled for" for this exact usage [(Relevant post)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72122/scheduled-on-vs-scheduled-for), like

> The meeting is scheduled for January 26th.

But I'm constantly tempted to use "will be held" in this kind of usages. Just to make sure if it's correct before I'm using it more often, is it common to use "will be held" to specify the time that the event will take place?

> The meeting will be held on January 26th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that expression is perfectly fine, as long as the verb's theme (a meeting, an event, a conference, etc.) is something that can be "held".

"Is scheduled for" has been more popular than "will be held on" since the 1940s in the [Google ngrams corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20scheduled%20for%2C%20will%20be%20held%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20scheduled%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20held%20on%3B%2Cc0), but a regular web search turns up 26 million hits for the former term and over 40 million for the latter. In any case, both expressions are correct and widely used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :D